# Unable to get Select2 tag values from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I am trying to get tag values from view to controller.

Here is what I am doing: my model attribute for getting Select2 values:

In model:

```
 public string[] TagList { get; set; }
```

In the view I have a select like this:

```
  <select id="TagList" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"></select>
```

For making it tag select, I am using the `select2` library and this jQuery code:

```
 $("#TagList").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',']
    });
```

Very simple code I don't have any predefined tags to populate just adding any tag entered in select.

But how do I bring the tag values from the view to the controller using `string[] TagList` ?

Help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier pass the tag list parameters as a string (comma separated) and convert it to array inside the controller.